# Dialogflow Messenger loads Google Fonts

Tags: fonts, dialogflow-es

I am working on a client, which is using google dialogflow messenger as a chatbot on their website. Due to german law, I have to prevent this extension to load fonts from googles fonts.google.com website. Does anyone knows a way to intercept these requests or to prevent them in the first place?

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Hi @Paul Werner, Dialoglow Messenger by default uses google fonts. If you want to prevent the Dialogflow Messenger extension to prevent loading fonts from fonts.google.com, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).